# AllowCrossTargeting in .fsproj files

Tags: f#

What's the effect of having

```
<AllowCrossTargeting>true</AllowCrossTargeting>
```

in a fsproj file? I can't find any documentation about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search the F# 3.0 sources for `AllowCrossTargeting`, it only appears in one place: [`fsharp/src/fsharp/Salsa/salsa.fs, line 686`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/Salsa/salsa.fs#L686).

Since it appears to be a write-only property as far as F# is concerned, my guess is that it has something to do with allowing the F# compiler to run on one version of the .NET framework whilst targeting another version. Other than that, searching Google for the property name only turns up `.fsproj` files -- so it doesn't appear `AllowCrossTargeting` does anything at all right now.